# IdTcpClient repeat ReadLn command

Tags: delphi, indy, delphi-xe5

I want to make a function on the Idtcpclient that repeats the ReadLn command.
But how can i do this? I don't want to use a timer because a timer is slow.
I allready searched on google but i don't understand it..

Comment: That sounds like a task for server, not for client...

Comment: But when i send a command to the client the client can't read it... Thats why i want to repeat it.

Answer (score 0):

The client can be placed in a separate thread, and use a loop to repeat the ReadLn until it succeeds. The time out can be given as an argument to ReadLn so that the next try will happen after the timeout interval. Make sure to handle connection loss, for example by reconnecting in a loop.

Comment: But when i place readln in a loop the application run very slow, just like when i put it in a timer

Comment: @jwz why should the main application run slow if the ReadLn is in a separate thread? The thread will wait until there is data, and repeat if there is no data. The main app thread will not be touched until there is data.

Comment: Oooh in a seperate thread, but how can i do that? I now try to use the backgroundworker component but i don't know how that works, i can make the events...

Comment: @mjn: There is no need to use a timeout in the case of a thread. Let `ReadLn()` block until data arrives, then call `ReadLn()` again and let it block, repeating as needed. When a disconnect occurs, a blocked `ReadLn()` will raise an exception, which can then be used to terminate the thread, or reconnect, etc as needed.

Comment: @jwz104: you can use a `TIdThreadComponent` component, which runs a worker thread and triggers its `OnRun` event (and others) within that thread. Or you can derive a new class from `TThread` and override the `Execute()` method, then create instances of that class when needed.  Search around, there are plenty of examples of using `TIdTCPClient` with threaded reading.

Answer (score 0):

I create a unit to my program, I hope to help you:

```
unit uSerialAuthentication;

interface

uses System.SysUtils, IdTCPClient, IdThreadComponent, FMX.Dialogs;

type
  TSerialAuthentication = class (TObject)
    IdTCPClient: TIdTCPClient;
    procedure IdThreadComponentRun(Sender: TIdThreadComponent);
  public
    constructor Create (Host : string; Port: Word);
    destructor Destroy; override;
    procedure OnConnect(Sender: TObject);
  end;
var
  idThreadComponent   : TIdThreadComponent; // Thread
  Access : Boolean;

implementation

{ SerialAuthentication }

procedure TSerialAuthentication.OnConnect(Sender: TObject);
begin
  ShowMessage('Connected');
  IdThreadComponent.Active  := True;
end;

constructor TSerialAuthentication.Create(Host : string; Port: Word);
begin
  IdTCPClient := TIdTCPClient.Create();
  IdTCPClient.Host := Host;
  IdTCPClient.Port := Port;
  IdTCPClient.OnConnected := OnConnect;
  idThreadComponent           := TIdThreadComponent.Create();
  idThreadComponent.OnRun     := IdThreadComponentRun;
  Access := False;
end;

destructor TSerialAuthentication.Destroy;
begin
  IdTCPClient.Disconnect;
  if idThreadComponent.active then
  begin
      idThreadComponent.active := False;
  end;
  FreeAndNil(IdThreadComponent);
  if Assigned(IdTCPClient) then
    FreeAndNil (IdTCPClient);
  inherited;
end;


procedure TSerialAuthentication.IdThreadComponentRun(Sender: TIdThreadComponent);
var
  recv : String;
begin
  recv :=  IdTCPClient.IOHandler.ReadLn();  // READ
  if length(recv)>0 then
    if recv = 'Ready' then
      Access := True
    else
      Access :=  False;
end;

end.
```